# Alternate between two threads (producer-consumer)

Tags: java

I'm attempting to edit my program so that the `incrementer` and `decrementer` classes are called alternatively, which `incrementer` being performed first. My aim is to be able to print the value of a shared variable (`sharedValue`) after each `increment`/`decrement` and hopefully see it toggle between `1` and `0`. Below is the code for my `main` class, a `semaphore` class and `incrementer` class (there is a class `decrementer` which is styled the same way as `icrementer` so i didn't include it).

main class

```
public class Main extends Thread {

    private static int sharedValue = 0;
    private static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    static int numberOfCycles = 20000;

    public static void increment() {
        semaphore.down();
        sharedValue++;
        semaphore.up();
    }

    public static void decrement() {
        semaphore.down();
        sharedValue--;
        semaphore.up();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        incrementer inc = new incrementer(numberOfCycles);
        inc.start();
        inc.join();

        decrementer dec = new decrementer(numberOfCycles);
        dec.start();
        dec.join();

        System.out.println(sharedValue);
    }
}
```

Semaphore class

```
private int count;
// Constructor
public Semaphore(int n) {
    count = n;
}

// Only the standard up and down operators are allowed.
public synchronized void down() {

    while (count == 0) {

        try {
            wait(); // Blocking call.
        } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
        }
    }
    count--;
}

public synchronized void up() {
    count++;
    notify(); 
}
```

incrementer Class

```
public class incrementer extends Thread{

    private int numberOfIncrements;

    public incrementer(int numOfIncrements){
        numberOfIncrements = numOfIncrements;
    } 

    public void run(){
        for(int i = 0; i <= numberOfIncrements; i++){
            Main.increment();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

So I have been reading through my notes and it occurred to me that I could use another mutex semaphore which can determine if the buffer is full or empty. Am I right with this approach?

Comment: And also indenting your code.

Comment: You explained what you want to achieve but did not mention the problem you have with your current code. So what is your question? :-)

Comment: Apologies, the problem is I have no idea how to edit the code to alternate between incrementing and decrementing the shared value, so it switches between 1 and 0. Do I need to use a loop or a boolean to store whether one thread is done.

Answer (score 1):

[Thread.Join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html)  causes your main thread to wait for the completion of the incrementer, then starts the decrementer and then waits for decrementer to complete.  If you want them to run concurrently, remove the two Thread.Join calls:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    incrementer inc = new incrementer(numberOfCycles);
    decrementer dec = new decrementer(numberOfCycles);

    inc.start();
    dec.start();
}
```

To print the shared value after each increment or decrement, move the **println** call to the **increment** and **decrement** functions of your main class:

```
public static void increment() {
    semaphore.down();
    sharedValue++;
    System.out.println(sharedValue);
    semaphore.up();
}


public static void decrement() {
    semaphore.down();
    sharedValue--;
    System.out.println(sharedValue);
    semaphore.up();
}
```

Also note that even with these changes you won't be observing the toggling between 1 and 0.  This is because the two threads don't start at the same time, and even if they did (e.g. using [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html)) you can't control the scheduling so they would progress differently.  If you really want to observe this output, you should make each thread wait for 1ms before and after calling semaphore.up() in order to give the other thread a chance to wait and acquire a permit from the semaphore.

```
public static void increment() {
    semaphore.down();
    sharedValue++;
    System.out.println(sharedValue);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1); //give time to other threads to wait for permit
        semaphore.up();
        Thread.sleep(1); //give time to other threads to acquire permit
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
}
```

There are more robust ways to get this kind of output from two threads, but I didn't want to make major modifications to your code.

Comment: This is really helpful but when I implemented it, it didn't work perfectly. It toggles between 1 and 0 for most of it but then towards the end it goes a bit awry and I get 0
1
2
3
2
3
2
3
2
1
0. Do you know why that might be? I've just tried testing it several times and I now realise it works sometimes but most the time it stops toggling between 1 and 0 , for some reason it will increment multiple times the before decrementing, can you help me fix it?

Comment: Sorry to spam messages but I just edited my code and increased the wait to 5ms and it works every time. Is this a bad way of fixing the problem. Is there a more efficient way? Thanks again.